# What can we say about the subset $\{x \in R \mid x^2 = ax+b\}$ when $R$ is a commutative rig (i.e. a ring without negatives)?

Tags: semiring

By a *rig*, I mean a ring whose elements don't necessarily have additive inverses, sometimes called a semiring. I want to ask very broad and potentially very naive question about solving quadratic equations in rig theory.

Suppose we're given:

- a commutative rig, call it $R$
- a pair of elements of $R$, call them $a$ and $b.$

Now define: $$X = \{x \in R \mid x^2 = ax+b\}$$

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Are there any theorems around that tell us anything interesting about $X$? e.g. which put bounds on its cardinality or tell us something interesting about how $X$ "sits inside" $R$?
>
> **Q1.** Are there any techniques available for finding the elements of $X$ explicitly?
>
> **Q2.** If the answers are "no", are there constraints we can put on $R$ that don't imply that addition in $R$ is cancellative, such that the answers to the above questions become "yes"?

I'm also interested in the potentially harder problem of finding $$\{x \in R \mid x^2+a'x+b' = ax+b\}$$

for $a',b',a,b \in R$.

Comment: The term "negatives" can be confusing (well, at least it confused me). I think you mean elements in a rig don't need to have additive inverse.

Comment: @Joanpemo, that's right. The terms "rig" and "semiring" are sufficiently standard that you can Google them and find explicit definitions, and even whole books about them.